# Netty set SSL handshake timeout does not work

Tags: ssl, netty

## Behavior

I'm using Netty 4.1.15.Final. I want to enable setHandshakeTimeout() in server side. I call the method `setHandshakeTimeout()` like this `sslHandler.setHandshakeTimeout(1,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` The value of HandshakeTimeout is set to a very small value so that the client and server can not complete the handshake since the handshake is timeout.

But it can not work when I use this in server.The connection can still be established between server and client. However when I do the same in client, the SSL connection can not be established , this is what I expect to see.

## Steps to reproduce

1. call the `sslHandler.setHandshakeTimeoutMillis(1);` or `sslHandler.setHandshakeTimeout(1,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` in server
2. do connect and SSL connection can be successfully established
3. do 1 and 2 again in client side, and SSL connection can not be established

my code is like this

```
 @Override
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    // I want to set the SSL handshake timeout
    SslHandler sslHandler = sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc());
    sslHandler.setHandshakeTimeoutMillis(1);
    sslHandler.setHandshakeTimeout(1,TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

    pipeline.addLast(sslHandler);

    // On top of the SSL handler, add the text line codec.
    pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
    pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast(new StringEncoder());

    // and then business logic.
    pipeline.addLast(new SecureChatServerHandler());
}
```

I use the [official SecureChat](http://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html) for an example

## Question

Am I doing it in a wrong way? If it is, how to set SSL handshake timeout of server in a right way? If not, why the SSL connection can be established and the handshake timeout is invalid?

Comment: Are you sure 1 nanosecond is quickly enough to do all expense calculations to prepare and verify the other party? Even a simple read operation from the ram takes 120 nanosecond

Comment: I have tried different values like 100,200,500,etc in milliseconds or seconds, connection still can establish, I'm curious why the timeout of handshake can not work

Answer (score 0):

Server-side SSL handshake timeout wasn't available in Netty until version 4.0.53.Final / 4.1.17.Final. See https://netty.io/news/2017/11/08/4-0-53-Final-4-1-17-Final.html for details.